# Is a potted grapevine better put under or outside a roof?

Tags: watering, containers, grape-vine

My two potted grapevines and I  just moved to a new apartment with a roof terrace.

The terrace has an acrylic glass roof with metal pillars and I want the vine to grow up the pillars and along/under this roof.

My options are:

- Put the pots in the edges of the terrace **under** the roof.
- Built something to hang the pots **outside the roof** next to the terrace.

Which will be better for the plants and lower maintenance in regard to watering?

We live in a vine area (southern  germany), so the amount of rain falling here seems to be suitable for non-potted grapevines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it'll make much difference - you live in an area where there's good rainfall, which is good for plants in the ground, but plants in containers still need watering, regardless. Marginally, a plant in a pot outside the roof will remain damper in winter than one under the roof, but during the growing season, you will need to water regularly whether the pots are in or outside. If they are under the roof, you will need to check them during winter to see whether they need water or not.

Comment: I agree, both ways will be the same. Of course, spider mites will be more likely where the foliage never gets wet, but as the vines will be trained under the roof anyway, it won't make much difference.

Comment: Thanks, Bamboo. 
To me that sound like a small plus for putting them outside of the roof: no checking against drying out in winter and less spider mites on the part of the foliage that is outside.

Comment: @Kaadzia - yes, but it really is marginal, plus the pots, and the roots within, will be more vulnerable to freeze risk than under the protection of the roof.

Comment: Damn, now I'm back again to a draw between them ;-) Outside: no winter-dry-out-maintenance, inside: less freezing risk. But at least now I can decide based on these fact. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: @Kaadzia - where you are, once you get past the end of October, its extremely unlikely your vines will need any water at all up till, maybe, March, possibly later, depending on the weather conditions.